# change discrete x zoo scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have this data.frame:

```
data<-structure(list(MESANIO = structure(c(2008.25, 2008.41666666667, 
2008.58333333333, 2008.66666666667, 2008.75, 2008.83333333333, 
2008.91666666667, 2009, 2009.08333333333, 2009.16666666667, 2009.25, 
2009.33333333333, 2009.41666666667, 2009.5, 2009.58333333333, 
2009.66666666667, 2009.75, 2009.83333333333, 2009.91666666667, 
2010, 2010.08333333333, 2010.16666666667, 2010.25, 2010.33333333333, 
2010.41666666667, 2010.5, 2010.58333333333, 2010.66666666667, 
2010.75, 2010.83333333333, 2010.91666666667, 2011, 2011.08333333333, 
2011.16666666667, 2011.25, 2011.33333333333, 2011.41666666667, 
2011.5, 2011.58333333333, 2011.66666666667, 2011.75, 2011.83333333333, 
2011.91666666667, 2012, 2012.08333333333, 2012.16666666667, 2012.25, 
2012.33333333333, 2012.41666666667, 2012.5, 2012.58333333333, 
2012.66666666667, 2012.75, 2012.83333333333, 2012.91666666667, 
2013, 2013.08333333333, 2013.16666666667, 2013.25, 2013.33333333333, 
2013.41666666667, 2013.5, 2013.5, 2013.58333333333, 2013.58333333333, 
2013.66666666667, 2013.66666666667, 2013.75, 2013.75, 2013.83333333333, 
2013.83333333333, 2013.91666666667, 2013.91666666667, 2014, 2014, 
2014.08333333333, 2014.08333333333, 2014.16666666667, 2014.16666666667, 
2014.25, 2014.25, 2014.33333333333, 2014.33333333333, 2014.41666666667, 
2014.41666666667, 2014.5, 2014.5, 2014.5, 2014.58333333333, 2014.58333333333, 
2014.58333333333, 2014.66666666667, 2014.66666666667, 2014.66666666667, 
2014.75, 2014.75, 2014.75, 2014.83333333333, 2014.83333333333, 
2014.83333333333, 2014.91666666667, 2014.91666666667, 2014.91666666667, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015.08333333333, 2015.08333333333, 2015.08333333333, 
2015.08333333333, 2015.16666666667, 2015.16666666667, 2015.16666666667, 
2015.16666666667, 2015.25, 2015.25, 2015.25, 2015.25, 2015.33333333333, 
2015.33333333333, 2015.33333333333, 2015.33333333333, 2015.41666666667, 
2015.41666666667, 2015.41666666667, 2015.41666666667, 2015.5, 
2015.5, 2015.5, 2015.5), class = "yearmon"), MesesRegistrado = c("4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", "4. Más de 24", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", 
"2. Más de 6", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "2. Más de 6", "3. Más de 12", 
"4. Más de 24", "2. Más de 6", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", 
"2. Más de 6", "3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "1. Menos de 6", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "1. Menos de 6", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "1. Menos de 6", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "1. Menos de 6", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "1. Menos de 6", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "1. Menos de 6", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24", "1. Menos de 6", "2. Más de 6", 
"3. Más de 12", "4. Más de 24"), Clientes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
110L, 238L, 270L, 300L, 309L, 321L, 295L, 345L, 373L, 376L, 409L, 
449L, 485L, 480L, 518L, 595L, 604L, 659L, 639L, 722L, 698L, 750L, 
775L, 802L, 868L, 894L, 974L, 1002L, 971L, 1060L, 1037L, 1047L, 
1089L, 1112L, 1155L, 1182L, 1226L, 1292L, 1375L, 1374L, 1416L, 
1457L, 1445L, 1451L, 1407L, 1467L, 1533L, 1574L, 1607L, 1595L, 
1716L, 1767L, 1719L, 1781L, 1807L, 1830L, 1822L, 17L, 1907L, 
82L, 1880L, 128L, 1912L, 173L, 1891L, 219L, 1888L, 280L, 1964L, 
337L, 1965L, 369L, 1946L, 421L, 1938L, 487L, 1945L, 556L, 1946L, 
641L, 1942L, 26L, 662L, 1948L, 117L, 598L, 1945L, 190L, 652L, 
1960L, 255L, 632L, 2023L, 321L, 627L, 2056L, 422L, 642L, 2099L, 
57L, 451L, 660L, 2139L, 182L, 410L, 647L, 2101L, 292L, 421L, 
675L, 2175L, 752L, 428L, 654L, 2172L, 995L, 435L, 690L, 2265L, 
1756L, 456L, 697L, 2285L, 2693L, 462L, 705L, 2382L)), .Names = c("MESANIO", 
"MesesRegistrado", "Clientes"), row.names = c(NA, -131L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list("MESANIO"), drop = TRUE)
```

Using this data I am producing the following using `ggplot()`:

```
g_evtrafico<-ggplot(data, 
                    aes(x = as.factor(MESANIO), 
                        y = Clientes,
                        group = 1))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  facet_grid(MesesRegistrado ~ .)+
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)+
  labs(title = "Flujo de Clientes", x = "Fecha", y = "Clientes")
```

The output is the following:

[image]

I'm trying to eliminate (programatically, because this is going in an rmarkdown doc) the x-axis labels which interfere with the correct reading of the graph. Ideally, the function would "decide" the breaks based on length of data. In this case, for example, I only need the year (column MESANIO is a yearmon zoo object).

I have tried adding scale_x_discrete() but nothing displays even if I put a generic break manually. I'm guessing this is due to the facets, but not sure.

Comment: You can also try something like theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)), to see if it works for you. Change the numbers to best fit your case.

Comment: Yes @Henrik, the error is caused by the inclusion of `...vars = list(MESANIO)...` - I submitted an edit to correct this but it was rejected.

Comment: I accepted it just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason to convert the x values of class `yearmon` to a discrete scale using `factor`, I think you should keep them as is and use `zoo::scale_x_yearmon`:

```
library(zoo)
ggplot(data, aes(x = MESANIO, y = Clientes) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  facet_grid(MesesRegistrado ~ .) +
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image]

You may use `n`, `breaks` and `format` arguments to fine-tune the appearance further.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `pretty_breaks` function from the `scales` package:

```
...
g_evtrafico <- ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(MESANIO), y = Clientes, group = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=10)) +
  facet_grid(MesesRegistrado ~ .) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Flujo de Clientes", x = "Fecha", y = "Clientes")
...
```

Comment: The x-axis is not appearing when this is applied... also I get warnings: In pretty.default(x, n, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: I did this myself on the data structure you provided and got labels for each year from 2009 - 2015 on the resulting plot output. I've since updated my answer to include the full ggplot code for reference. Could you try again?